# Sum of cubes with time limit of execution

Tags: c

How can I make the time limit for the execution of the code to be 2 seconds. The code calculates if a given number(the input)is expressible as the sum of two cubes in at least two different ways.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
int n, j, k, int_count;

scanf("%d", &n);

   int_count = 0;
   for (j=1; j<=n; j++) {
      for(k=j+1; k<=n; k++) {

          if(j*j*j+k*k*k == n)

          int_count++;
      }
   }
   if(int_count >= 2) {

      printf("YES");

   }
   else
   printf("NO");

}
```

Comment: Two seconds for what size of `n`? On what kind of machine? Could you specify your time limit in another way?

Comment: The input can be from 1 to 10^9 and it is not specified on what kind of machine.

Comment: Is your "two seconds" a limit? I mean, do you need to interrupt the process if it's taking more than 2 seconds? Or is it an optimization problem?

Comment: Sounds like a competition question;(

Comment: It says Warning: The time limit for
the execution of your program is set to 2 seconds, i.e. your program must produce its output within 2 seconds.

Comment: Hint: if `j` grows, `k` must shrink.

Comment: for the inner loop work in n - j * j * j space

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use time() or gettimeofday().

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main() {
    long n, j, k, int_count;
    time_t t;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    t = time(0);
    int_count = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        for(k = j+1; k < n; k++) {
            if(j*j*j + k*k*k == n)
                if(++int_count > 1) {
                    puts("YES");
                    return 0;
                }
            if (time(0) - t >= 2) {
                puts("timeout");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    puts("NO");
    return 0;
}
```